# CRASH gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupPolygonInstance::CreateEntities

Tags: crash, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have not been able to reproduce this crash myself ever but occasionally I see (on crashlytics) user getting this. I feel the frequency of crashing has increased with GoogleMaps version 3.3.0. I am getting this crash for iOS 12 and above.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Someapp                        0x101027058 gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupPolygonInstance::CreateEntities(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, id<GMSEntityResources>, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin<std::__1::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> >, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin::less<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> > >*, gmscore::renderer::Behavior*, char const* const&) + 311748
1  Someapp                        0x101027044 gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupPolygonInstance::CreateEntities(gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera> const&, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, id<GMSEntityResources>, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin<std::__1::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> >, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin::less<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> > >*, gmscore::renderer::Behavior*, char const* const&) + 311728
2  Someapp                        0x101021c90 gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupMultiZoomLinesInstance::UpdateEntities(float, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::Camera>, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, id<GMSEntityResources>, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin<std::__1::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned int, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> >, gmscore::renderer::ProxySortedRenderBin::less<gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::renderer::BaseEntity> > >*, gmscore::renderer::Behavior*, char const* const&) + 290300
3  Someapp                        0x10101bb94 gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupBehavior::UpdateInstanceMap(std::__1::map<unsigned long, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupInstance>, std::__1::less<unsigned long>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<unsigned long const, gmscore::base::reffed_ptr<gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupInstance> > > > const&, gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*, bool) + 265472
4  Someapp                        0x10101b428 gmscore::vector::GMSMarkupBehavior::Commit(gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer*) + 263572
5  Someapp                        0x100efa9e8 gmscore::renderer::EntityRenderer::Draw(bool) + 400
6  Someapp                        0x100f9ded4 -[GMSPhoenixRenderer drawForced:] + 6452
7  Someapp                        0x100f80bc8 -[GMSEntityRendererView draw] + 518060
8  Someapp                        0x100f7f224 -[GMSEntityRendererView displayLinkFired:] + 511496
9  Someapp                        0x100f7de10 -[GMSDisplayLink displayLinkFired:] + 506356
10 QuartzCore                     0x1f9308f90 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 636
11 QuartzCore                     0x1f93d2b10 display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 272
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4eeca8c __CFMachPortPerform + 188
13 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4f13690 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4f12ddc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4f0dc00 __CFRunLoopRun + 2096
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4f0d0b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
17 GraphicsServices               0x1f710d79c GSEventRunModal + 104
18 UIKitCore                      0x221887978 UIApplicationMain + 212
19 Someapp                        0x100511850 main + 16 (TripResultViewController+Validation.swift:16)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x1f49d28e0 start + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue but in **iOS 13** devices with **GoogleMaps 3.7.0 pod**.
The error only appears the first time I open the app (after installing it), but the rest of the executions are working well, maybe this give u some clues about the crash.

There is an open issue for de maps-sdk-for-ios that it's worth to keep an eye on it, because it seems to be related to a bug in the SDK:

[issue tracker link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148238890)

I hope this information helps to solve the problem or at least to throw some light on it ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue was originally reported here: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/issues/236

In our app we use Google Map SDK and I can reproduce this issue by zooming in on the map to the max (starting with version 3.3.0)

I reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148238890

Comment: My previous answer was deleted by this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters
No idea why he deleted it, even though it was pretty relevant.
I'm reposting the answer.